# Why does Gauss' Law derive a different electric field from the integration method?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electrostatics, electric-fields, gauss-law, integration

I was working on a very simple E&M problem and took two different approaches to it but got different answers - I'd be grateful if someone could spot the error in my logic!

A non-conducting solid sphere has a radius R and a total charge of Q distributed uniformly throughout the sphere. What is the magnitude of the electric field at point P, a distance r from the center of the sphere?

[image]

I noticed that the integrated approach differed from the Gauss' Law approach by a factor of 3. Could anyone tell me why that is?

Comment: This has a piecewise solution, i.e., a different field within than without.

Comment: On this site you are expected to use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) for all math. Please do not post images of handwritten math. You may post images of diagrams.

Comment: Please be aware that in general check-my-work question are off-topic here. We want to answer conceptual questions, not check your math. I decided to answer your question rather than vote to close it because your mistake was conceptual, and a common one for students to make.

Comment: @G.Smith Ah, thank you for the heads up! I'll keep this in mind for the future.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have made a conceptual error when integrating. You have used $r$ to mean both the radius at which you are measuring the field and the radius of a shell of charge $dq$ contributing to that field. These are two different radii.

If you had drawn in your diagram where the shell of charge $dq$ is, the distinction would probably have been clear.

As honeste_vivere mentioned in a comment, you have only calculated the interior field. The exterior field has a different form.

You seem to be relying on knowing the field of a charged shell. If you have never computed that field using integration over the shell, that is an instructive exercise to do to convince you that the field outside is the same as that of a point charge and the field inside is zero.